# What are the difference between a black holes and a black branes?

Tags: black-holes, string-theory, branes

1. I want to know the fundamental difference between a black hole and a black brane?
2. What is the planar limit?

Comment: Did you have a look at the relevant wikipedia pages and/or textbooks? I think you should try to make your question more focused.

Comment: google is a better resource for such questions. please refer there.